# Getting an error message that i am not familiar with doing the dogglers app for the google developers unit 2 app

Tags: kotlin

heres the link for the project . -> https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-project-dogglers-app?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-project-dogglers-app#2

package com.example.dogglers.adapter

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.GridLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.dogglers.R
import com.example.dogglers.const.Layout
import com.example.dogglers.const.Layout.GRID
import com.example.dogglers.data.DataSource
import com.example.dogglers.data.DataSource.dogs
import com.example.dogglers.model.Dog
import kotlinx.coroutines.selects.select

/*** Adapter to inflate the appropriate list item layout and populate the view with information* from the appropriate data source*/
class DogCardAdapter(
    private val context: Context?,
    private val layout: Int

): RecyclerView.Adapter<DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder>() {
    val dogs = DataSource.dogs



    // TODO: Initialize the data using the List found in data/DataSource

    /*** Initialize view elements*/

    class DogCardViewHolder(view: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view!!) {
        val dogImageView: ImageView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.pics_of_dogs)
        val dogNameText:TextView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.dogs_name)
        val dogAgeText:TextView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.dogs_age)
        val dogHobbyText:TextView?=view?.findViewById(R.id.dogs_hobbies)



        // TODO: Declare and initialize all of the list item UI components


        fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder {
            // TODO: Use a conditional to determine the layout type and set it accordingly.
            //  if the layout variable is Layout.GRID the grid list item should be used. Otherwise the
            //  the vertical/horizontal list item should be used.




            val adapterLayout = when (viewType) {
                Layout.GRID -> LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_list_item,parent,false)
                else -> LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.vertical_horizontal_list_item,parent,false)
            }
            return DogCardViewHolder(adapterLayout)

                // TODO Inflate the layout

            }

            // TODO: Null should not be passed into the view holder. This should be updated to reflect
            //  the inflated layout.

        }



        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dogs.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder, position: Int) {
            // TODO: Get the data at the current position
            // TODO: Set the image resource for the current dog
            // TODO: Set the text for the current dog's name
            // TODO: Set the text for the current dog's age
            val dogData = dogs[position]
            holder.dogImageView?.setImageResource(dogData.imageResourceId)
            holder.dogNameText?.text= dogData.name
            val resources = context?.resources
            holder.dogAgeText?.text= resources?.getString(R.string.dog_age,dogData.age)
            holder.dogHobbyText?.text = resources?.getString(R.string.dog_hobbies,dogData.hobbies)
            // TODO: Set the text for the current dog's hobbies by passing the hobbies to the
            //  R.string.dog_hobbies string constant.
            //  Passing an argument to the string resource looks like:
            //  resources?.getString(R.string.dog_hobbies, dog.hobbies)
        }
    }

    //fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder
```

Comment: What is the error message you're asking about?

Comment: Class 'DogCardAdapter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder defined in androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: And what don't you understand about that error message? (It seems pretty self-explanatory to me.)

Comment: could you explain what that means and what i would need to get rid of the error?

Comment: because when i make the class abstract and try to run the app is says cannot creat an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: I got it now I had to implement the member in a different area of the code. even though it was one of the areas that were pre-written had to move it out of the class.